# Python output is abnormal

Tags: python

I designed a movie ticket billing program

```
Full ticket: 250 dollar
Half ticket: 175 dollar
The first number is the full ticket price
The second number is half the ticket price
```

The program output effect is:

```
The number of groups is: 3
Group 1: 5 3
Group 2: 6 4
Group 3: 7 6
Output:
The first set of charges: 1775
The second set of charges: 2200
The third set of charges: 2800
```

But the output result of my program is abnormal, and normal output data cannot be displayed
I hope everyone can help and help!!
My code:

```
lisa=input("The number of groups is:")
for ta in range(1,int(lisa)+1):
  usc=input(f"Group {ta}:").split()
  s1=usc[0]*250
  s2=usc[1]*175
  s3=s1+s2
print(f"The {ta}th group should be charged:",str(s3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lisa=input("The number of groups is:")
res=[]
temp=['first','second','third']
for ta in range(1,int(lisa)+1):
  usc=input(f"Group {ta}:").split()
  s1=int(usc[0])*250
  s2=int(usc[1])*175
  s3=s1+s2
  res.append(f"The {temp[ta-1]} set of charges: {s3}") # no need to put outide s3
print("\n".join(res))
```

Comment: hey you got the output now?

Comment: The problem is that you are getting input as strings and not converting to int

Comment: not yet
The error message displays: list index out of range

Comment: Now check it I have modified single line